# When is this object deallocated?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[[PPFormEngine alloc] init] downloadAndCacheFormDataIfNeeded];

    return YES;
}
```

I am using ARC.

Anyone know how the system handles the PPFormEngine object?
Is that object going to exist a couple of more seconds after we return from that method and then autoreleased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `downloadAndCacheFormDataIfNeeded` is asynchronous -- returns immediately and kicks off a background task to do the download -- then the lifespan of the instance of `PPFormEngine` is entirely an implementation detail of that class.

If it holds a strong reference to itself during the download, it'll stick around.  If not, it'll be deallocated rather quickly;  either immediately after `downloadAndCacheFormDataIfNeeded` or sometime later if it happened to fall into an autorelease pool.

Regardless, the safest implementation would keep a strong reference in an instance variable that is set to nil when the download is complete.   Hopefully, `PPFormEngine` has a callback of some kind so you know when to nil out the reference.

Answer (score 2):

ARC should add a call to `release` such that the object will be deallocated before the call the to `return YES` is reached. So no, it will not exist a few more seconds after the method returns. It won't exist for any number of seconds after the method returns.

Now, having said the above, I don't know the implementation of the `downloadAndCacheFormDataIfNeeded` method. If its implementation retains `self` until the download and caching is complete, then there won't be an issue.